# Removing malware

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

My laptop get infected by virus or just malware. Gradually I get rid of it. It was forcing me to pay by a card otherwise I will get jailed for breaking a number of some sort of laws. I caught it at movie streaming site.
Anyway, now when I restart my laptop a pop up window pops up saying that it cannot start an exe file (the malware file I have removed).

How can I disable that script or something looking for that malware file?
Is that something to do with register?

Comment: Going to need a few more specifics here.  What's the exact error you're getting (screenshot would be nice, otherwise full details e.g. file name would still help)?  What sort of malware did you remove?  Best bet in any case is probably to just [nuke from orbit](http://www.craftyn.com/attachments/nuke-it-from-orbit-jpg.1044/).

Comment: Please try the suggestions mentioned in the "duplicate" question. There, the community has summarized all of the important steps you can take. If you tried something but didn't succeed, just [edit] your question, mention what you did, and `flag` for reopening so we can work on the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to disable startup entries.

Although the best course of action may be to format and reinstall. You don't know what's left of the virus on your computer, or whether it's clean for sure.

Additionally, if you actually used your credit card to pay for the threats made by the virus, I'd highly recommend reporting it to your bank and getting a new card issued. That puts you at high risk for identity theft.

Comment: I did not pay and have never paid for such things.